# If $f$ is analytic on the unit disc, and $\lim_{z\to 1}f(z)=\inf$，can $f$ be continued such that $1$ is a pole if $f$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If a power series uniformly converges to $f$ on the unit disc and diverge at $1$, $1$ is a singular point of $f$. 
If $f$ suits the condition: $f(z) \rightarrow \inf $ as $z\rightarrow 1$ for all $z$ on the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$, 
can this function be continued to be a analytic function on $\mathbb{D} \cup U$,where $U$ is a deleted neighborhood of $1$?If so is $1$ always a pole or $1$ can be essential singularity?

If necessary, assume that $1$  is a isolated singular point on the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$.

Thank you for your time.

Update:

1. Thanks. The power series may not uniformly converge on unit disc. Although it is not related to this question, the word "uniformly" should be deleted.
2. Thanks for some examples in the comments, $1$ can be branch point sometimes. So if we add another condition and restate the problem as follows:
   If $f(z)$ can be analytic continued on $\mathbb{D}\cup U(1)$ and $1$ is not a branch point, is $1$ always a pole or can be a essential singularity?
   i.e. Can $f(z)$ goes to $\inf$ on "half" of the neighborhood of a essential sigularity?

Comment: So $\ln(1-z)$ is excluded by $f(z)\to\infty$ for $z\to 1$? I think not. So you need to further control the singularity.

Comment: How can a power series converge uniformly on the disc and go to infinity at $1?$

Comment: Why don't you take examples ? What about things like $f(z) = \left(\frac{z-2}{z-1}\right)^{1/2}$ (branch point at $z=1$) and $f(z) = e^{1/(1-z)}$ ? (essential singularity at $z=1$) ?

Comment: I didn't see the uniform convergence. Did you mean local uniform convergence ? Anyway most power series don't have an analytic continuation beyond the unit disk, and those having an analytic continuation  don't have to be meromorphic at their singularities.

Comment: For user 1952009: $f(z)=e^{1/(1-z)}$ doesn't have limit at $z=1$. For zhw and user1952009: Sorry, I do mean local uniform convergence, so I correct it in the update.

Comment: I gave an example where $z=1$ is an essential singularity. If an isolated singularity is not an essential singularity then it is a pole (possibly of order $0$)

Comment: $f(z) = e^{1/(1-z)}$ , $\lim_{z \to 1, |z| < 1} f(z) = \infty$ but $\lim_{z \to 1, \Re(z) > 1} f(z) = 0$

Comment: If $z=1$ is an isolated singularity of $f$ (ie. it is analytic on $0 < |z-1| < \epsilon$) then $\lim_{z \to 1} f(z) = \infty$ iff $z=1$ is a pole (proof : $g(z) = 1/f(z)$ is bounded around $z=1$ so it is a removable singularity, thus $g$ has a zero of finite order $n$ and $f$ a pole of order $n$)

Comment: Assume $z$ goes to $1$ on the curve $r=\frac{1}{2}\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle of $1-z$ and $r $ the modulus of $1-z$, then the real part of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is always 1/2 and $f(z)$ is bounded

Comment: But here we just know $f(z)$ have limit on $\mathbb{D}$ intersect with $U(1)$， instead of a neighborhood of $1$.